# Regex: Select/Find all tags that contains a particular word

Tags: regex, windows

I have this king of tags in every one of my 200 html pages.

`<title>Top Cars | My number | (en),resources</title>`

`<title>Top Cars | My number | (en),prices</title>`

So, I need a regex to find just those tags that contains word: `prices`

I try this: `<title>(\w+)prices<\/title>` and this: `\b<title>\w*(prices)\w*<\/title>\b`

but doesn't work:

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. This should do the trick:

```
<title>.*?prices<\/title>
```

You were using `\w`, which only matches word characters (letters, digits and underscores), but not spaces and other characters. `.` matches any character.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/ZXXoy7/1

Edit: You could also follow user @tripleee's suggestion of `[^<>]` instead of just `.`
Also, although regex provides a simple solution in this case, it's often better to use a proper HTML parser to, well, parse HTML.

Comment: You probably want `[^<>]` instead, to avoid straddling malformed tag boundaries.

Comment: `[^<>]` means ?? please write the full formula to understand better